# What is the difference between column-oriented and row-oriented databases?

Tags: database, rdbms

What are examples of column-oriented DBMSs?

Is there any difference in querying (do both use SQL?)? Performance? Data modeling?

When and why should I use one over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go: [Column-Oriented DBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-oriented_DBMS)

Comment: So nice and blunt. I love it.